# adding a new article in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have 2 pages (say A and B)
If I add an article on page B I would like to display a short href item in page A that takes me to the just added article on page B. I am doing this using Zoomla (and php - well not yet php)

Thank you for any idea and guidance

Comment: I'm not clear what you ask for! If you want to navigate to a page and to a exact place of a page, you can do it with simply using an anchor

Comment: In the administrative control panel, I create an article for a section1 of categoryM, right after I save it I would like there is some automatic processing to create a link to that article in another page :-D, That link appears in another page I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add it with manually with following steps..

just copy the url of the page B like `index.php?xxxxxxx` to the end so that after enable rewrite remain work..

and then paste the link on the page A article..

Comment: how can I read the content of the index.php in Joomla ? because the link I would like to add in should be put in the index.php file, I am unable to edit the index.php right now

Comment: you **don't** edit the index.php file! That file is not supposed to be touched. Go to the Article Manager, go to edit Article A, and put the link in there.